# How to join characters?

Tags: c, string, strcpy, strcat

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    char rez[100] = "\0";
    char t = 97;
    char temp;
    strcpy(temp, t);
    strcat(rez, temp);

    printf("%s", rez);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to join the character 'a' to the result but strcpy and strcat command do not work.
How could I do that if the char t should be an ASCII code?

> warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
> strcpy(temp,t);
> note: expected 'char * restrict' but argument is of type 'char'
> char * __cdecl strcpy(char * **restrict** _Dest,const char * **restrict** _Source);

[image]

Comment: **Protip:** `char rez[100] = "\0"` Double quotes doesn't suits on it.

Answer (score 0):

Both functions work with *strings*, not with individual characters. It’s often convenient to create a new string of length 1 from the `char`, and work with that:

```
char str[] = { t, '\0' };
```

Now you can concatenate that.

Alternatively, you can implement the concatenation manually by just writing the character into the right location of the resulting array:

```
const len = strlen(rez);
rez[len] = t;
rez[len + 1] = '\0';
```

… or you could use the `sprintf` function:

```
sprintf(rez, "%s%c", rez, t);
```

In all cases you need to take care to not accidentally write outside of the bounds of the string.

In your specific case, none of these make sense, since `rez` is empty to start with; you’re not *concatenating anything*, you’re just writing a single character into a buffer.

```
rez[0] = t;
rez[1] = '\0'; // for good measure
```

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy` and `strcat` expect both of their arguments to have type `char *` *and* that both arguments point to the first character of a zero-terminated *string*.

The problem is that neither `t` nor `temp` are pointers, and neither are the first characters of a string so passing `&t` or `&temp` will work.

If you want to append a single character to `rez`, you can do something like

```
/**
 * Use character literals instead of raw ASCII codes - 
 * it’s easier to understand, it will work as expected
 * on non-ASCII systems, and you’re less likely to make
 * a mistake.
 */
t = 'a'; 
size_t len = strlen(rez);
/**
 * Overwrite the terminator with the value in t, 
 * then write the terminator to the following element
 * (strictly not necessary in this case, but it never
 * hurts to make sure)
 */
rez[len++] = t;
rez[len] = 0;
```

You could also use the `sprintf` library function:

```
sprintf( rez, "%s%c", rez, t );
```